# Installing RCU for Oracle Data integrator runs on Error

Tags: repository, creation, utility

I am trying to installing RCU for Oracle  Repository Creation utility however everytime I try to install the development repository it runs on error.

Steps to reproduce the issue.

1. I run rcu bat file
2. Create repository/system load and product load
   3.Choose oracle as database type/hostname localhost, port 1521 servicename xe, username sys and the password (I am able to login into oracle database with this login information) (I am using oracle 18c express
3. I am using the prefix dev
   [image]
4. I am adding password for schemas, supervisor, and for the repository user.
5. I am not touching the tablespaces
6. I start the install and several error messages are dropping. like

Ora-65096 invalid common user or role name
[image]

Ora-01917 DEV_STB user does not exists
[image]

Ora-00955 The name has already been in use by another object.

My question what could be the problem with the installation of RCU and How can I resolve the issue ?
Funny thing is I am trying to install odi and RCU based on step by step video still something went wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are logging to CDB with the service name XE. You need to log into the PDB (Plugable database).
Just change the service name from XE to XEPDB1 while connecting to the DB through RCU and your issue should be resolved.